# How to wait for two blocks of code to run in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shiny-reactivity

Suppose I have the following blocks of codes in Shiny:

```
library(shiny)

rv <- reactiveValues()

observe({
  # Event A
  # Code Block A
  # The code below signals the end of Code Block A
  rv$event_a <- F
  rv$event_a <- T
})

observe({
  # Event B
  # Code Block B
  # The code below signals the end of Code Block B
  rv$event_b <- F
  rv$event_b <- T
})

observe({
  rv$event_a
  rv$event_b
  if(rv$event_a & rv$event_b) {
    # Do something only after both Code Blocks A and B finish running.
    # Code Block C
  }
})
```

As you can see, I'm toggling the reactive values in Blocks A and B from `FALSE` to `TRUE` to trigger Block C to run.

I want to write the code so that **the cycle can repeat itself**:

**Some trigger -> Block A & B -> C ->**

**Some trigger -> Block A & B -> C ...**

My questions are the following:

1. How can I make Code Block C run **only once, when** both Code Block A and B **finished** running?
2. How else can I achieve triggering Code Block C without the weird toggling of reactive values (between `FALSE` and `TRUE`) that I am currently relying on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have accomplished this before by eventObserving or eventReacting to the reactive objects or reactiveValues generated by 'code-block-a' or 'code-block-b'. I have attached 3 small shiny app examples to give insight into this approach using different methods (hopefully these will help answer the original question - or at least give some ideas).

This app will create a table in 'code-block-a' with as many rows as the sliderInput has selected. Once this 'event_a()' reactive is updated 'code-block-b' subsets one row. Once 'code-block-b' updates its object 'event_b()' a modal is displayed showing the selected row in a table.

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)


ui <- fluidPage(
  sliderInput("slide", "slide", value = 5, min = 1, max = 10),
  actionButton("go", "go"),
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {


  rv <- reactiveValues(tr1 = 0, el = 0)
  final <- reactiveValues()



  #CODE BLOCK A#
  #takes slider input and makes a table with that many rows
  event_a <- eventReactive(input$go,{
    nums <- seq(1, input$slide, by = 1)
    l <- 1:length(nums)

          tibble(Letter = letters[l],
                        Value = nums)

  })

  #trigger next series of events in response to event_a()
  #observeEvent(event_a(),{
  #  rv$el <- rv$el + 1
 # })

  ##CODE BLOCK B##
  # this will subset a row of data based on the value of the reactive
  event_b <- eventReactive(event_a(), {
    row <- sample(1:nrow(event_a()), 1)
    event_a()[row,]
  })

  #look for changes in event_b() to trigger event C
  #the loading of event_b will trigger the modal via rv$tr1
 # observeEvent(event_b(), {
 #   rv$tr1 <-  rv$tr1 + 1
 # })

  #side effect make a table from event_b() to be shown in modal
  output$modal_plot <- renderTable({
    event_b()
  })


  ##CODE BLOCK C##
  #launch modal showing table
  observeEvent(event_b(), {
    showModal(modalDialog(title = "Table",
                          "This is a table",
                          tableOutput("modal_plot"),
                                             inline = T))


  })




}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Or if all your 'code-block' are observers you can use reactive values that are updated inside of an observer. I have found this flexible if multiple things need to happen to trigger something downstream:

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)


ui <- fluidPage(
  sliderInput("slide", "slide", value = 5, min = 1, max = 10),
  actionButton("go", "go"),
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {


  rv <- reactiveValues(tr1 = 0, el = 0)
  final <- reactiveValues()



  #CODE BLOCK A#
  #takes slider input and makes a table with that many rows
  event_a <- eventReactive(input$go,{
    nums <- seq(1, input$slide, by = 1)
    l <- 1:length(nums)

          tibble(Letter = letters[l],
                        Value = nums)

  })

  #trigger next series of events in response to event_a()
  observeEvent(event_a(),{
    rv$el <- rv$el + 1
  })

  ##CODE BLOCK B##
  # this will subset a row of data based on the value of the reactive
  event_b <- eventReactive(rv$el, ignoreInit = T, {
    row <- sample(1:nrow(event_a()), 1)
    event_a()[row,]
  })

  #look for changes in event_b() to trigger event C
  #the loading of event_b will trigger the modal via rv$tr1
  observeEvent(event_b(), {
     rv$tr1 <-  rv$tr1 + 1
   })

  #side effect make a table from event_b() to be shown in modal
  output$modal_plot <- renderTable({
    event_b()
  })


  ##CODE BLOCK C##
  #launch modal showing table
  observeEvent(rv$tr1, ignoreInit = T, {
    showModal(modalDialog(title = "Table",
                          "This is a table",
                          tableOutput("modal_plot"),
                                             inline = T))


  })




}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Furthermore, if you are wanting something that iterates like a loop here is an example that describes the above process, but plots each row of data in a modal one row at a time and asking for user input each time:

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)


ui <- fluidPage(
  sliderInput("slide", "slide", value = 5, min = 1, max = 10),
  actionButton("go", "go"),
  tableOutput("df"),
  tableOutput("user_choices_table")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {


  rv <- reactiveValues(tr1 = 0, el = 0)
  final <- reactiveValues()


  #STEP 1
  #some function/series of events that gives us a some data
  data1 <- eventReactive(input$go,{
    c <- seq(1, input$slide, by = 1)
    l <- 1:length(c)
    out_table <- tibble(Letter = letters[l],
                        Value = c)
    return(out_table)
  })

  #side effect - return data1 to UI
  output$df <- renderTable({
    data1()
  })

  #number of max iterations we will go though (dependent number of rows in data1)
  num_iterations <- reactive({
    nrow(data1())
  })


  #trigger next series of events in response to data1()
  #this will get us from 0 to 1 and another observer will be used to add
  #all the way up to the max_iterations
  observeEvent(data1(),{
    rv$el <- rv$el + 1
  })
  #this ^ observer is like entering the loop on the first iteration

  ##STEP 2##
  ##start/continue the "disjointed-loop".
  #Subset data1 into smaller piece we want based on rv$el
  #this will be our 'i' equivalent in for(i in ...)
  #data subset
  data2 <- eventReactive(rv$el, ignoreInit = TRUE, {
    data2 <- data1()[rv$el,]
    return(data2)
  })

  #side effect make a plot based on data2 to be shown in modal
  output$modal_plot <- renderPlot({
    d <- data2()
    ggplot()+
      geom_col(data = d, aes(x = Letter, y = Value,  fill = Letter))+
      theme_linedraw()
  })


  #once we get our data2 subset ask the user via modal if this is what they want
  #the loading of data2 will trigger the modal via rv$tr1
  observeEvent(data2(), {
    rv$tr1 <-  rv$tr1 + 1
  })

##STEP 3##
  #launch modal showing plot and ask for user input
  observeEvent(rv$tr1, ignoreInit = TRUE, {
    showModal(modalDialog(title = "Make a Choice!",
                          "Is this a good selection?",
                          plotOutput("modal_plot"),
                          checkboxGroupInput("check", "Choose:",
                                            choices = c("Yes" = "yes",
                                                        "No" = "no"),
                                            inline = T),
                          footer = actionButton("modal_submit", "Submit")))

  })

  #when user closes modal the response is saveed to final[[character representing number of iteration]]
  observeEvent(input$modal_submit, {
    final[[as.character(rv$el)]] <- input$check
    if(rv$el < num_iterations()){
    rv$el <- rv$el + 1 #this retriggers step2 to go again
    } else {
      rv$done <- rv$done + 1
    } #breaks the disjointed loop and trigger start of next reactions
  })

  #and the modal is closed
  observeEvent(input$modal_submit, {
    removeModal()

  })

  final_choice <- eventReactive(rv$done, ignoreInit = TRUE,{
    enframe(isolate(reactiveValuesToList(final))) %>%
      mutate(name = as.numeric(name),
             value = unlist(value)) %>%
      arrange(name)

  })

  output$user_choices_table <- renderTable({
   final_choice()
  })




}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer!  Following your suggestion, I tried `eventReactive()` but int he end, I found a way to get around my problem by using `debounce`